# Spring: Generate new csrf token programmatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, csrf

I'm trying to make a webapp that will run on a single HTML page that will allow users to interact with the server through JavaScript and ajax. I'd like to make my requests safe against csrf attacks by including a csrf token in each request.

Because my webapp will only be operating on a single page, I can't use the ${_csrf.token} (or something like that) syntax in the view because the view is going to be a json object. Instead I'd like to have a url like "/security/csrf" that returns a token associated with the user's session. (Yes, this won't be a restful service exactly.)

Is there some way for me to generate a csrf token that Spring Security will be able to access when verifying a log-in? And additionally, is there a flaw in using csrf tokens in this way?

Comment: token per request will kill caching. token per session is just as safe. in your first html response, include the csrf token in a meta tag, like the docs say: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-include-csrf-token-ajax

Comment: So if I just use one token per session, will Spring continue to accept the same token across multiple requests? @NeilMcGuigan

Comment: yes, you can use the same token across requests (in the same session).

Comment: Okay, thank you! I'll try this approach out!

Comment: It works! Now to remove the pesky redirects.

Comment: If I want to change the token value at every new request then how because of i didnt want to repeat the token value if anybody catch my token value then they can acess my request so plz help me or suggest me right one method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Token per request will kill caching. Token per session is just as safe.

In your first html response, include the csrf token in a meta tag, like the docs say: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-include-csrf-token-ajax

You can use the same token across requests (in the same session)